# Solved: Java Ant doesn't package somehow external, local .ttf Fonts in .jar

Tags: java, fonts, jar

I've written a program in Java with NetBeans and built a simple GUI to it, but used some external .ttf Fonts which I put manually in the package in the src folder. The Class that uses the Fonts is in the same package as the .ttf file. I put the code down below how I imported it in Java (which I got from StackOverflow :) ). My problem is that if I run my program in Netbeans it works perfectly fine, but if I build it with Java Ant and execute the .jar, it won't load the fonts. I already read that the .jar file cannot work with the Java "File"-Class somehow, but I also tried it to use it with getResourceAsStream, but it didn't work either. Sorry, it's my first question on stack overflow, but I would be glad if someone could help me out.

Edit: Updated the Code

Package GUI does Contain the Class EntryDlG and Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf File

```java
public class EntryDLG extends javax.swing.JDialog {

  public static Font MontserratSemiBold20; //Declaration

  public EntryDLG(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) { //Constructor

    importFonts();
    jLabel2.setFont(MontserratSemiBold20);
  }

  public static void importFonts(){

        try{
            MontserratSemiBold20 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(new File("src\\GUI\\Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf"))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge1 = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge1.registerFont(MontserratSemiBold20);
            }
            catch(IOException | FontFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Java-Ant:

```
Compiling 16 source files to C:\...\DartTournamentApp\build\classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 6 files to C:\...\DartTournamentApp\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\...\DartTournamentApp\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\...\DartTournamentApp\build
Building jar: C:\...\DartTournamentApp\dist\DartTournamentApp.jar
```

Maybe the problem is because Ant only compiles 16 Files (The Projects contains excactly 16 Java-Class Files). In this 16 Files are the .ttf Files NOT included!

Solved: 
After even more research, i tried:

```
MontserratSemiBold20 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("GUI/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf")).deriveFont(20f);
```

And because now the path is correct in Netbeans and in .jar, it works for both.

Comment: please provide more source code, it looks you need to put a absolute path

Comment: Are you sure the font is copied into the jar or alongside it?

Comment: posted the relevant code of the class

Comment: @TesX What do you mean with alongside it?

Comment: Well, since you used a relative file path, please check if that file can be reached from the current working directory (I assume it's the same of the dir in which the jar file is, but, again, please check)

Comment: I dont know what exactly u mean, but the .jar does contain the .ttf File. But the path is possible wrong but i tried nearly every combination, and the only combination of the path that worked is the code above. I need to use src//GUI//Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf . I cant leave the src// out.

Comment: Thanks guys anyway